# rails create bidirectional relation before_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I build my relations:

```
  # models
  class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :practices, through: :lead_practices
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :practices
  end

  class Practice < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :leads, through: lead_practices
  end

  # leads controller
  def create
    @lead_profile = LeadProfile.new lead_profile_params
    puts "lead practice #{@lead.practices.first}"
    puts " practice lead #{@lead.practices.first.lead.first}"
  end

  # view:
  <%= form_for @lead do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :something %>
    <%= f.fields_for :practices do |practice_builder| %>
      <%= practice_builder.text_field :something_else %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

The problem is in the create action, I can access the practice through lead but I cannot access the lead through practice. This becomes an issue when I want to access the lead through practice in the practice's before_create callback:

```
class Practice < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :do_something

  def do_something
    lead.first.do_something # raises an exception because practices is nil, even though it should be populated with the relation
```

This seems like a common use case. How can I access the reciprocal relation?

Comment: The line of code that raises an exception looks wrong: if it's really part of the `Practice` model, it ought to be `leads.first.do_something`, no?

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. I didn't copy the exact code in question @ToddAgulnick

Comment: Nit: the code is still wrong: s/lead/leads/.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `has_and_belongs_to_many` instead of `has_many :through`? That is:

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :practices
end

class Practice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :leads
end
```

I don't know whether this will improve your situation, but it seems like it's worth a shot, as writing it this way means that ActiveRecord doesn't have to work as hard to understand the inverse relationship between the two associations, which seems key here.